# Is MPI_Reduce blocking (or a natural barrier)?

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing

I have the code snippet below in C++ which basically calculates the pi using classic monte carlo technic.

```
    srand48((unsigned)time(0) + my_rank);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < part_points; i++)
    {
            double x = drand48();

            double y = drand48();

            if( (pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)) < 1){ ++count; }
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&count, &total_hits, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(my_rank == root)
    {
            pi = 4*(total_hits/(double)total_points);

            cout << "Calculated pi: "  <<  pi << " in " << end_time-start_time <<  endl;
    }
```

I am just wondering if the MPI_Barrier call is necessary. Does MPI_Reduce make sure that the body of the if statement won't be executed before the reduce operation is completely finished ? Hope I was clear. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, all collective communication calls (Reduce, Scatter, Gather, etc) are blocking. There's no need for the barrier.

Comment: The MPI standard allows for early exit of participating processes. The only collective call that guarantees synchronisation is `MPI_Barrier`.

Comment: And I don't agree with @HD189733b: if the root finishes its computation early, it has to sit and wait in the reduce until everyone has contributed. There is zero possibility of crash or incorrect result.

Answer (score 5):

Ask your self if that barrier is needed. Suppose you are not the root; you call Reduce, which sends off your data. Is there any reason to sit and wait until the root has the result? Answer: no, so you don't need the barrier.

Suppose you're the root. You issue the reduce call. Semantically you are now forced to sit and wait until the result is fully assembled. So why the barrier? Again, no barrier call is needed.

In general, you almost never need a barrier because you don't care about temporal synchronization. The semantics guarantee that your local state is correct after the reduce call.

Answer (score 4):

Blocking yes, a barrier, no. It is very important to call `MPI_Barrier()` for `MPI_Reduce()` when executing in a tight loop. If not calling `MPI_Barrier()` the receive buffers of the reducing process will eventually run full and the application will abort. While other participating processes only need to send and continue, the reducing process has to receive and reduce.
The above code does not need the barrier if `my_rank == root == 0` (what probably is true). Anyways... `MPI_Reduce()` does not perform a barrier or any form of synchronization. AFAIK even `MPI_Allreduce()` isn't guaranteed to synchronize (at least not by the MPI standard).

Comment: As this answer appears to contradict the selected answer and there's no evidence that it has been voted down, can someone comment on whether this is actually wrong?

Comment: This answer is only half-correct. The receiving buffers **might** run full. Most MPI libraries implement flow control mechanisms that prevent such thing from happening.