# Error in rank ID using MPI_Reduce

Tags: c, mpi

Well, I'm doing some homework using MPI + C. In fact, i just wrote a small code of programing assignment 3.2 from Peter Pacheco's book, called  An Introduction to Parallel Programming . The code seems to work for 3 or 5 processes... but when I try more than 6 processes, the program breaks.

I'm using a very "bad" debugging approach, which is to put some printfs to trace where problems are occuring. Using this "method" i discover that after MPI_Reduce, some strange behaviour occurs and my program gets confused about the ranks IDs, specifically rank 0 disappears and one very large (and erroneous) rank appear.

My code is below, and after it, i'm posting the output for 3 and 9 processes... I'm running with

```
mpiexec -n X ./name_of_program
```

where X is the number of processes.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void)
{
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

long long int local_toss=0, local_num_tosses=-1, local_tosses_in_circle=0, global_tosses_in_circle=0;

double local_x=0.0,local_y=0.0,pi_estimate=0.0;

int comm_sz, my_rank;

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);         

if (my_rank == 0) {
    printf("\nEnter the number of dart tosses: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%lld",&local_num_tosses);
    fflush(stdout);
}

//
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Bcast( &local_num_tosses, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    srand( rand() ); //tried to improve randomness here!

for (local_toss=0;local_toss<local_num_tosses;local_toss++) {
    local_x = (-1) + (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX / 2);
    local_y = (-1) + (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX / 2);

    if ( (local_x*local_x + local_y*local_y) <= 1 ) {local_tosses_in_circle++;}
}


MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Reduce
(
    &local_tosses_in_circle,
    &global_tosses_in_circle,
    comm_sz,
    MPI_LONG_LONG_INT,
    MPI_SUM,
    0,
    MPI_COMM_WORLD
);  

printf("\n\nDEBUG: myrank = %d, comm_size = %d",my_rank,comm_sz);
fflush(stdout);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (my_rank == 0) {
    pi_estimate = ( (double)(4*global_tosses_in_circle) )/( (double) comm_sz*local_num_tosses );
    printf("\nPi estimate = %1.5lf \n",pi_estimate);
    fflush(stdout);
}

MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, 2 outputs:

(i) For 3 processes:

```
Enter the number of dart tosses: 1000000

DEBUG: myrank = 0, comm_size = 3

DEBUG: myrank = 1, comm_size = 3

DEBUG: myrank = 2, comm_size = 3
Pi estimate = 3.14296
```

(ii) For 9 processes: (note that the \n output is strange, sometimes the it does not work)

```
        Enter the number of dart tosses: 10000000


        DEBUG: myrank = 1, comm_size = 9
        DEBUG: myrank = 7, comm_size = 9


        DEBUG: myrank = 3, comm_size = 9
        DEBUG: myrank = 2, comm_size = 9DEBUG: myrank = 5, comm_size = 9
        DEBUG: myrank = 8, comm_size = 9



        DEBUG: myrank = 6, comm_size = 9

        DEBUG: myrank = 4, comm_size = 9DEBUG: myrank = -3532887, comm_size = 141598939[PC:06511] *** Process received signal ***
        [PC:06511] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
        [PC:06511] Signal code:  (128)
        [PC:06511] Failing at address: (nil)
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mpiexec noticed that process rank 0 with PID 6511 on node PC exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when the third argument of [MPI_Reduce](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) is `1`, not `comm_size` (because the number of elements in each buffer is 1):

```
MPI_Reduce
(
    &local_tosses_in_circle,
    &global_tosses_in_circle,
    1, //instead of comm_size
    MPI_LONG_LONG_INT,
    MPI_SUM,
    0,
    MPI_COMM_WORLD
);
```

When you increase the number of processes, `MPI_Reduce` overwrites other stuff in the stack of the function, e.g. `my_rank` and `comm_sz`, and corrupts the data.

Also, I don't think you need any of the `MPI_Barrier` statements. `MPI_Reduce` and `MPI_Bcast` are blocking anyway.

I wouldn't worry about the newlines. They are not missing, but in some other place in the output, probably because many processes write to stdout at the same time.

By the way: Debugging using `printf`'s is very common.

Comment: Very nice Rafael, thanks a lot ! It solved my problem ! In fact, the third argument of MPI_Reduce is the size of data..if it's not a vector, the correct value is 1...really ! I'm feeling dumb :-( lol

About the barrier, i think the same as you...but take a look in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284419/is-mpi-reduce-blocking-or-a-natural-barrier) Stack Overflow post..it's really confusing !

Comment: I see where the posting by beer is coming from. I will probably get into this and answer you sometimes. If you are not executing MPI_Reduce in a loop, as beer mentions, dropping the MPI_Barrier is definitely ok.

Comment: Thanks very much Rafael, for the effort in helping me ! Much appreciated !