# MPI_REDUCE causing memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran, mpi, reduce

I have recently encountered a weir behavior. If I run the following code on my machine (using the most recent version of cygwin, Open MPI version 1.8.6) I get a linearly growing memory usage that quickly overwhelms my pc.

```
program memoryTest

use mpi

implicit none

integer            :: ierror,errorStatus      ! error codes
integer            :: my_rank                 ! rank of process
integer            :: p                       ! number of processes
integer            :: i,a,b

call MPI_Init(ierror)
call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_rank, ierror)
call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, p, ierror)

b=0
do i=1,10000000
    a=1*my_rank
    call MPI_REDUCE(a,b,1,MPI_INTEGER,MPI_MAX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,errorStatus)
end do

call MPI_Finalize(ierror)

stop
end program memoryTest
```

Any idea what the problem might be? The code looks fine to my beginner's eyes. The compilation line is

```
mpif90 -O2 -o memoryTest.exe memoryTest.f90
```

Comment: The tag [tag:fortran] should be always used when referring to Fortran. Use the [tag:fortran90] or [tag:fortran2003] or others if you need to distinguish between versions for some reason.

Comment: Can confirm on OpenSuSE Linux. Looks like a library issue.

Comment: Reproducible on Gentoo Linux w/ gcc-5.2.0 and OpenMPI 1.10.0

Comment: I'm curious - can someone confirm that it is not reproducable with MPICH or Intel MPI?

Comment: I can reproduce it with mpich2 3.0.4 and gfortran 4.9.3 (meaning the memory just blows up). Intel MPI 5.1.1 however runs it like a breath.

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed in a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284419/is-mpi-reduce-blocking-or-a-natural-barrier).

The problem is that the root process needs to receive data from other processes and perform the reduction while other processes only need to send the data to the root process. So the root process is running slower and it could be overwhelmed by the number of incoming messages. If you insert at MPI_BARRIER call after the MPI_REDUCE call then the code should run without a problem.

The relevant part of the MPI specification says: "**Collective  operations  can  (but  are  not  required  to)  complete  as  soon  as  the  caller's
participation in the collective communication is finished.**  A blocking operation is complete
as soon as the call returns.  A nonblocking (immediate) call requires a separate completion
call (cf. Section
 3.7
). The completion of a collective operation indicates that the caller is free
to modify locations in the communication buffer.  It does not indicate that other processes
in the group have completed or even started the operation (unless otherwise implied by the
description of the operation).  **Thus, a collective communication operation may, or may not,
have the effect of synchronizing all calling processes.**  This statement excludes, of course,
the barrier operation."

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit more support for macelee's answer: if you run this program to completion under MPICH with MPICH's internal memory leak tracing/reporting turned on, you see no leaks.  Furthermore, valgrind's leak-check reports

```
==12866== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12866==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12866==   total heap usage: 20,001,601 allocs, 20,000,496 frees, 3,369,410,210 bytes allocated
==12866== 
==12866== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12866==
```

Comment: Gcc's -fsanitize=leak on the other hand shows many leaks, probably false positives. At least for OpenMPI (which is the target of the question, not MPICH). I suppose I wouldould have to compile the MPI library with that flag too.

Comment: I find MPICH's internal leak tracing helpful for not only things that MPICH leaked but also for things the user forgot to free, such as attributes, datatypes, info objects, file handles, etc.   I bet openMPI has something similar but I'm not as familiar with OpenMPI

Comment: Please note that the usefulness of memory debugging tools may be limited in MPI applications. For better performance (which is probably the top priority when implementing MPI), developers may intentionally use 'unsafe' techniques (such as writing data into uninitialized memory). In fact according to in its FAQ, OpenMPI is not Valgrind clean.