# MPI_BARRIER inside a loop working faster than expected in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

This is not a question to help me to solve a problem, is more related to the MPI implementation and how it works with `MPI_BARRIER` in Fortran.

I have a do loop that basically prints my Variables to an output file.
The do loop looks like:

```
do j = 1, Jmax
  Call MPI_GATHERV(u_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,u_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_GATHERV(v_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,v_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_GATHERV(r_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,r_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_GATHERV(T_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,T_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
end do
```

This loop works perfectly, but for big matrices MPI just hangs. By big I mean 8001x8001 and bigger.

I wanted to try to add a `MPI_BARRIER` at the end of the do loop, and I expected to take much more time, but it turned out to be the opposite. This is the new version.

```
do j = 1, Jmax
  Call MPI_GATHERV(u_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,u_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_GATHERV(v_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,v_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_GATHERV(r_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,r_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_GATHERV(T_old(1,j),Imax,MPI_REAL8,T_oldGlobal(1,j),ImaxRecv,&
                   Displacement,MPI_REAL8,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  Call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
end do
```

But like I said, the process is faster than the original to the point that now MPI ends the task without any error (before I had error 134).

Here is the questions. Why is this performance? Since we are always thought that Barrier adds sometimes unnecessary synchronizations when collective communications are involved. This case...

I am looking forward to here your comments.

Comment: If MPI just hangs for such small arrays as 8000^2 (no, that is NOT big!), you are likely to have a bug there. Normally, the barrier should not have almost any effect there as the collective calls are blocking. Please see [mcve] to see how to prepare a piece of code we can really examine. What you show is not enough, we can only guess.

Comment: Error 134 tells nothing. Certainly not if you don't tell us which MPI implementation you are using. But even the complete error is not useful without the complete code.

Comment: Such a loop can lead to a lot of unexpected messages on rank 0, and hence performance can drop significantly. Inserting a `MPI_Barrier()` can reduce the amount of unexpected messages, so you can see the performance increase

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet This reminds me a question with a similar mode of crash caused by overfilling the buffer of the receiver, but I cannot find it now. It requires a lot of iterations of the loop.

Comment: @VladimirF, `MPI_BCAST` is blocking but not necessarily synchronising. Process might diverge in time and, depending on how the operation is implemented internally, having all processes aligned in time after the barrier call could have a sizeable impact on the performance. There are (or at least used to be, haven't looked at the newer code base) calls to `MPI_BARRIER` before each collective call that shuffles large amounts of data around in Quantum ESPRESSO and those barriers are enabled only when building with Open MPI.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes I know. As I said, there was a similar question with a crash before. I just can't find it.

Comment: fwiw, Open MPI has the `coll/sync` collective module. it automatically perform a barrier before or after a collective operation. there are MCA (e.g. tunable) parameters to control how often this happens on a given communicator.

Comment: @HristoIliev what do you mean by `MPI_Bcast()` is blocking ? a given implementation can simply issue a `MPI_Send()` on the root task, and if the message is small enough, this will virtually return immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs colleagues. @GillesGouaillardet your point makes a lot of sense . My guess that the error 134 is still debatable and my impression is that there is no a white and black here in regards to using Barriers in these type of do loops. The bottom line is that the performance increased a lot just by adding the MPI_BARRIER

Comment: @VladimirF I also agree with other members in this threads bloking does not mean synchronized. I will need to do the paralel Output soon since I realized that collecting all the data at the root and write the output file from root is very inefficient.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, blocking as in blocking vs. non-blocking operations. A broadcast that completes immediately because of buffering is still a blocking operation. And I meant `MPI_GATHERV` of course, no idea why I've written `MPI_BCAST`. Not that it changes anything.

Comment: @JulioMendez, some hints if you wish to dig deeper into the issue. Several years ago I was investigating some performance issues of the collective operations in Open MPI's `coll/tuned` on our cluster's InfiniBand fabric. The way I did it was to simply take the code from Open MPI and replace the internal calls to send/receive/datatype/etc. with the `MPI_...` equivalents. Then you can use any tracing library like VampirTrace or Score-P and examine the trace/profile in something like Vampir or Cube and look for inefficiency patterns when the processes are not aligned in time.

Comment: @JulioMendez Yes, I know it does not mean syncgronized and I know this has been discussed before. I have said that already. I will find the other question. It may even be a duplicate. Yes, I was wrong in the first comment. Yes, I knoe about it. It happens, no need for evyrone to come and ping me about that, I have already revoked that.

Comment: This is the related question. Possible duplicate? It is not a completely exact duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33779051/721644